# Why is the associated model being touched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models:

```ruby
class DeliveryMethod
  has_many :subscription_delivery_methods
  has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subscription_delivery_methods
end

class SubscriptionDeliveryMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :delivery_method
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription_delivery_method
  has_one :delivery_method, :through => :subscription_delivery_method
end
```

I assign delivery method to Subscription like this:

```ruby
s.delivery_method = DeliveryMethod.find 1
```

When I do the assignment like above Rails updates `subscription_delivery_methods`, which is expected:

```ruby
UPDATE subscription_delivery_methods SET delivery_method_id = 1, updated_at = '2011-10-27 09:11:23' WHERE subscription_delivery_methods.id = 2
```

But when I do `s.save!` it touches `DeliveryMethod`, which is unexpected and unwanted:

```ruby
UPDATE delivery_methods SET updated_at = '2011-10-27 08:40:53' WHERE delivery_methods.id = 1
```

I tried all kinds of `:readonly` and `:touch` flags on the associations to prevent this update from happening. I haven't succeeded. Do you guys know how to stop it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think your wrong in your relationship assignment :
try to write : DeliveryMethod belongs to many ...
And tell me if its works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `autosave`?

```
 has_one :delivery_method, :through => :subscription_delivery_method, :autosave => false
```

Comment: Didn't work. 1) has_one doesn't have `:autosave` argument. 2) I tried `:autosave` with `belongs_to` -- it didn't have any effect :(